# Name for Theorem: Extension of Uniformly Continuous Function on Dense Subset?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

There is a theorem that *a bounded linear transformation from a dense subspace of a normed vector space to a Banach space has a bounded linear extension to the whole space*. This seems to be sufficiently important to get a name - the **Bounded Linear Transformation (BLT) Theorem**.

In large part (it remains to prove linearity), this follows from a similar more general result in Metric spaces that *a uniformly continuous function from a dense subset of a metric space to a complete metric space has a uniformly continuous extension*.

So, does this more general theorem have a name ?

Comment: Regarding the name, probably the best one can say is that it's statement is its name. If you want to know is how to look the theorem up in a book, I suggest looking in a topology book under a chapter with a title like "metric spaces" or "complete metric spaces" or "completeness in metric spaces" or something like that.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks: I have a reference for the proof, https://math.berkeley.edu/~sagrawal/su15_math104/lec17_unifcont.pdf (page 2) it's only the name I was curious about - any idea who first proved it ?